Power outage during operation of servo motor causes mechanical damage
The servo motor is connected to a 1:10 warm gear which is driving a heavy axle at a speed of 240 rpm.
The inertia of the axle is high, when there is an unforeseen power outage, the deceleration is almost instantanous to zero, causing big force on the axle which breaks it.
The servo drive is DELTA ASD-A2-1543-m, I need the drive to decelerate to zero in like 100ms instead of instantanously to avoid mechanical damage.
-Are there any changes in the drive settings that can help with this?
-using UPS is very expensive, but is it possible to put capacitors on the DC bus of the servo to keep it alive for a fraction of a second after power outage, and use this time for deceleration?
Thanks

Would adding a flywheel to the input shaft of the worm drive help?

... That's assuming that the controller isn't actively braking the motor. If it is, maybe there's a way to reduce the torque to zero as soon as the power failure is detected. I can't tell from a quick skim of the user manual.

can the shaft be connected to a ratchet one way bearing?

worm gears are notorious for not allowing the output to spin the input. Use a different reduction method if you want it to be allowed.

The worm gear is the issue as @TigerGuy mentioned, I'm trying not to do mechanical changes to the machine. I just want to keep the servo alive for a fraction of a second after power cut. Anyway to do this?

The servo drive detects power outage and brakes the servo motor instantly causing the damage. This was solved by

disabling power loss detection (P2-65 Bit12 = 1)
connection a relay to the power supply to give an emergency stop signal to the servo drive when there is a power loss
making sure the drive doesnt brake when any errors start to occur (P01-32 to 10)

This completely solved the issue, just make sure emergency stop decelaration time is long enough not to cause damage, and short enough to conclude the deceleration before the drive is completely out of power, for my case i set it to 500 ms.
